# Computer Sleeps Randomly

Tags: sleep

My computer randomly initiates sleep. I've checked the other questions with the same name - none of those issues are ones I have. Things run cool (I checked the temps), the power button is not depressed, and no magnetic clasps.

I checked dmesg for clues:

http://pastebin.com/5mbYsZ1K

http://pastebin.com/UZ0mrZVE

Sleep occurs at: "Preparing system for mem sleep"

I saw there were some network card messages before it, so I tried turning off my wireless. This didn't help. This occurs on both windows and linux.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the problem is independent of the OS, it OS almost certainly a HW issue of some sort.

Comment: @StephenRauch that's a good point. Any ideas about what things to check besides temperatures?